# Styling Text without HTML Tag?

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to style Plain text without HTML tag in HTML.

Example:  like I type in HTML some plain text say

```
    hello world   -> Can I style this plain text without any tag

    and not like

  <div> Hello World </div>
```

Comment: Yes...but it would be a universal style - and therefore not be able to style individual words. `body {font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; }`. Obviously you would want to markup your text content correctly though, using `<p>` tags for paragraphs etc.

Comment: You can apply default styling to all text in your document using the CSS universal selector (*) or the body tag.

Comment: default styling  using (*) will not have any effect on plain text if it is not inserted inside a tag...e. hello world as plain text without inserting it in tag like <p>, <div> will be plain text only. how will you give width to this "hello world" if it is not inside p,div,span etc

Comment: Really? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xYDeY/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Plain text is contained within an element: the `body` element:

```
<body>
    Hello, world!
</body>
```

Because of this, you could style this text by simply styling the `body` element:

```css
body {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Depending on the context though, CSS3 does provide two [pseudo-element selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) which could be used for this: `:first-line` and `:first-letter`.

To style the "H" you could simply use:

```css
body:first-letter {
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

If there was a `<br>` element separating your first line from another line, you could also make use of `:first-line`:

```
<body>
    Hello, world!<br>
    Second line.
</body>
```

```css
body:first-line {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/9KXG2/1/).

Comment: I noticed even though plain text put inside head tags, I still need to use body selector instead of head selector to style it.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a `span` or something of that nature to target certain parts of text. With only the use of css a tag is required to style the text.

You can achieve that effect like so with `span`,

```
<p>I can style <span>this</span> text with the use of a tag</p>

p span {
    color: teal;
}
```

I found this [article on adding an underline to certain words](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/underline-individual-words/). With the use of a script you could tweak this around to work how you want it to and without you adding an html tag by hand. Instead the jQuery will be adding the tag for you.

Comment: hey this is not my question...i said is there a way to give plain text styling in without inserting it in any tag???

Comment: That is the answer to your question, no you can't. You need to use some tag to target the text.