# how to add css to text without a tag in a div?

Tags: html, css

I want to style "Login" text , can I do it without "label" tag ?

here's my code

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="WebFontKit/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

<body>
  
    <div class="logindiv">
      <label class="login">Login</label>
```

Comment: Of course it is possible, please explain what exactly is the desired result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling Text without HTML Tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164438/styling-text-without-html-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. See the fiddle

```css
div.logindiv::before {
  content:'Login';
  position: top;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="WebFontKit/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="logindiv">
      </div>
  </body>
    
</html>
```